# Conditional for ruby how to display only once with no repeating

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So my `songs` table is like this:

```
+----+---------------+
| id | artist        |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | One direction |
|  2 | One direction |
|  3 | The Beatles   |
|  4 | One direction |
|  5 | The Beatles   |
|  6 | Drake         |
|  7 | Drake         |
|  6 | One direction |
+----+---------------+
```

If I do the code that I've been trying to figure out
I think it will look like this.

```
<% @songs.each do |song|  %> 
    <% if song.artist != "The one that appears on this list" %>
        <%= song.artist %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I want the output should be just like this 
No repeating, just displaying only one time each.

Output: **One direction**, **The Beatle**s, **Drake**

Comment: If you have / need `@songs` anyway, you could use `@songs.map(&:artist).uniq` – otherwise, it's better to run a specific query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [pluck](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) to grab all artist names and add uniq to them:

```
Song.pluck(:artist).uniq
```

This will give you the unique list of artists you have. You can then map on it to create your html output.

It also works on @songs directly :)

Comment: `Song.distinct.pluck(:artist)` might be quicker if you have lots of records in the db, as `distinct` is run on the database

Answer (score 3):

It's best to do this with ActiveRecord, so the filtering is performed on the database, and not in Ruby, as databases are more performant:

```
Song.select(:artist).distinct
```

You could also consider to create a new `Artist` model and change your `Song`:

```
belongs_to :artist
```

Checkout the [Active Record Associations Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Song.select(:artist).uniq

or you can create **artist model** and filter according to it.....

Answer (score 0):

You could [`group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) the records first and than display the artist only once per group:

```
<% @songs.group_by(&:artist).each do |(artist, songs)|  %> 
  <%= artist %>

  <% songs.each do |song| %>
    <%= song %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```